# Not getting desired output while running macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have  below sas macro.I want to create a dataset where I want to multiply each year with some weight

for each variables  in the macro variable chk_var.But it is not giving any result .In log it is showing

```
MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2015 is FALSE

MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2014 is FALSE

MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2013 is FALSE

MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2012 is FALSE

MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2011 is FALSE

MLOGIC(WEIGHT_AVG): %IF condition year=2010 is FALSE
```

Any help will be appreciated.

My macro -

```
%let chk_var=Total_Shareholders_Funds Secured_Loans Total_Debt___Loan_Funds
    Total_Liabilities Sundry_Debtors Inventories Cash_and_Bank_Balance
    Total_Current_Assets Total_Current_Liabilities Sls_Turnover_Operat_Incom
    Net_Sales Total_Income Operating_Profit Interest Gross_Profit  Profit_Before_Tax Tax 
    Reported_Net_Profit Adjusted_Net_Profit Debt_Equity_Ratio Interest_Cover_Ratio
ROCE RONW;


%put %sysfunc(countw(&chk_var.));


options mprint mlogic symbolgen;

%macro weight_avg;

Data capital_all_3;

set capital_all_2;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&chk_var.));

%let a=%scan(&chk_var.,&i.);

%if year=2015 %then &a._15=6*&a.;

%if year=2014 %then &a._14=5*&a.;

%if year=2013 %then &a._13=4*&a.;

%if year=2012 %then &a._12=3*&a.;

%if year=2011 %then &a._11=2*&a.;

%if year=2010 %then &a._10=1*&a.;

%end;

run;

%mend weight_avg;

%weight_avg;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your %IF condition is comparing the literal string 'year' to the literal string '2010' (etc), which will always be false. Macro %IF statements only ever compare literal strings, but usually at least on of the literal strings comes from a macro variable being resolved, so something like:

```
%IF &year=2015 %THEN ...
```

Your macro doesn't include a macro variable named YEAR, though, so I suspect you're trying to reference a variable from the data set. Macro variables and data set variables are two completely different things, so this won't work.

Try changing it to be a data step IF:

```
if year=2010 then &a._15=6*&a.;
```

etc.

Macro programs are a mixture of macro code and normal base SAS code, and it's very important to be clear on which is which!